# How to read file changes in azure blob storage?

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to read a file from azure blob storage as byte stream as below:

```java
    public static final String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=*;AccountKey=*;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("inputfile");
            CloudBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("test.txt");
            InputStream input =  blob.openInputStream();
            InputStreamReader inr = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
            String output = IOUtils.toString(inr);
            System.out.println(output);

            System.out.println("read is success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am able to read the file from azure file storage. I am trying to create something like Java WatchService where if there is any change in file i want read the changes and print data for example below let say i have file test.txt file in blob initially it have data some thing like below

`"Hello"`

My program should print `"Hello"`.

After some time i will update file with `"world"`, now i want to print only `"world"` which is a new change in file.

Is it possible in azure blob storage? I saw the API of `azure_blob_storage` but didn't find any method like java WatchServices. Could you please help me how can i read file changes in azure blob storage?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such service. However, you can use Event Grid which is an event repository, and subscribe to changes in your Azure storage account (new / updates blobs), then, trigger some function (maybe an Azure Function) to return the changes to client.

[image]

And here's a step by step how to do it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/blob-event-quickstart-portal